# How to remove Rails nested association before running validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I'm using Mongoid and embedded documents. I am using the standard approach to using a hidden form field of `_destroy` with a value of `1`. This works fine, except for when a validator is run which includes the association that I'm trying to delete. For example:

```
class Thing
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :actions
  validate :uniqueness_of_actions

  def uniqueness_of_actions
    subjects = actions.map(&:subject)
    subjects_are_unique = subjects == subjects.uniq
    errors.add(:actions, 'must have unique subjects') unless subjects_are_unique
    subjects_are_unique
  end
end
```

What is the proper way to remove/exclude the associations marked for destruction before validations are run which might include them?

Answer (score 1):

Try something along these lines.

```
class Artist < AR::Base
  has_many :songs

  validate :custom_thing

  def custom_thing
    songs.reject{ |x| x._destroy}.each do |a|
      # magic here
    end
  end
end
```